# How to implement magnet effect without flicking in Qt

Tags: qt

I am developing a magnet effect in my Qt project.There two widgets(**Master** and **Slave**).**Slave's** left border will be moved to **Master's** right border(**that's I called magnet effect**) when they are 30 pixels away from each other when **Slave** is moving,**then** they enter **TOGETHER_STATE**.**Once** they enter **TOGETHER_STATE**,**Slave will be moved when Master is moving,not vice versa.**They enter SEPARATE_STATE when **Slave's** left border is more than 30 pixels away from Master's right border when it is moving.As far as I know Teamviewer has similar effect.

One way to implement magnet effect is that move **Slave** to **Master's** right border using **move function** **in Slave's moveEvent** when condition described above is satisfied. But it will contribute to **flicking** because move widget in moveEvent will lead to infinite recursion.

Do anyone have any good ideas?Did I make myself understood?

Comment: is slave master's child ? If yes then call move of slave from parent's events. (May be MouseDragEvent or WindowMoveEvent).

Comment: @AbhishekBansal As I said,I used move fuction in Slave's moveEvent and it contributed to flicking. Qt notes that calling move() or setGeometry() inside moveEvent() can lead to infinite recursion.That's all I got,maybe I missed something important.

Comment: Yes you are corect. if you move from inside moveEvent you will get flickering there is no way you can avoid flickering this way. MoveEvent gets called after widget has already been moved. So if you call move from inside it will again call moveEvent. So best way to do this is to call move from outside slave widget.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal Yep,I just want to find out some ways out of box?

Comment: There is nothing in QT wihich will provide you this functionality out of the box AFAIK.